# Selenium - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/reactivestreams/Publisher

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, log4j

I am creating a Maven project for Selenium in eclipse. Don't know why it threw log4j error (It didn't used to earlier, before upgrading Eclipse). The error is as follows -

[image] I have already added "log4j.properties" file under src/main/resources as -

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Also added dependency as following in POM.xml -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

Artifacts used -

Eclipse - Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)

Maven artifact id - maven-archetype-quickstart - v1.4

Selenium version - 3.141.59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not related to `log4j`. The error is for `org.reactivestreams.Publisher`. Add the following Maven dependency to get it:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure to update the project after adding the dependency.